# Absolute Reference not remaining absolute

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets.  The first has Column A and B (Last Name and First Name) with the list of names running down the columns.  On the second worksheet, I want to merge the names together in one row across columns.
I am using the following formula:

```
=LEFT('SINGLE PLATFORM '!D5,1) & "." & 'SINGLE PLATFORM '!C5
```

When I drag the formula across the row to the right, the `D5 / C5` changes to `E5 / D5` but what I need it to do is change to `D6 / C6`, `D7 / C7`, etc.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your formula isn't absolute to begin with.

Comment: Any joy with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula from:

```
=LEFT('SINGLE PLATFORM '!D5,1) & "." & 'SINGLE PLATFORM '!C5
```

to:

```
=LEFT('SINGLE PLATFORM '!$D5,1) & "." & 'SINGLE PLATFORM '!$C5
```

Comment: I tried this but it still does not maintain the absolute column reference.  I think it has something to do with the data being in columns and I am trying to drag the formula across a row but I just can't nail down the issue.

Comment: =LEFT('SINGLE PLATFORM '!$D5,1) & "." & 'SINGLE PLATFORM '!$C5  is making both the column and row absolute for whatever reason

Comment: Well the formula that I am suggesting should work based on your question. Could you pls provide some more details? Like Test data.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you're after:

```
=LEFT(OFFSET('SINGLE PLATFORM '!$D$5,COLUMN('SINGLE PLATFORM '!D$5)-COLUMN('SINGLE PLATFORM '!$D$5),0),1) & "." & OFFSET('SINGLE PLATFORM '!$C$5,COLUMN('SINGLE PLATFORM '!C$5)-COLUMN('SINGLE PLATFORM '!$C$5),0)
```